# Existing Hash Function for uuid_t

Tags: c++, hash, uuid

Does `uuid.h` (package: uuid-dev) have any functions for hashing a `uuid_t` variable?

It would be alot nicer to use if it exists than rolling my own. If there isn't a function, any advice on a hash procedure that could produce a relatively reliable unique result?

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #define GUID UUID
    #define generateGUID          UuidCreate                    // returns RPC_S_OK, RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY, RPC_S_UUID_NO_ADDRESS
    #define hashGUID(gUid)        hash<long>()(gUid.Data1) ^ (hash<short>()(gUid.Data2) << 1) >> 1 ^ hash<short>()(gUid.Data3) << 1 ^ hash<char>()(gUid.Data4[0]) << 1
#else
    #define GUID uuid_t
    #define generateGUID          uuid_generate_random
    #define hashGUID(gUid)        ???
#endif // WIN32

namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct hash<GUID>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(const GUID& gUid) const
        {
            using std::size_t;
            using std::hash;

            return hashGUID(gUid);
        }
    };
}
```

**Edit** Usage: in a std container as a key

```
std::unordered_map<GUID, Component> components;
```

Comment: What is the use case?  Why do you want to hash a UUID?  Is `size_t` 32 bits or 64 bits on your system?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I've made an edit to demonstrate my use case

Comment: Can you use boost?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to hash UUIDs so that you can store them in a hash table, I suggest something simple:

```
 std::size_t operator()(const GUID& gUid) const
 {
     const uint64_t* half = reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(&gUid);
     return half[0] ^ half[1];
 }
```

The above assumes you're on a 64-bit platform (so uint64_t is as wide as size_t).